# Convert 3D data point to normalized (2D) figure point in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

Consider positioning some text on a 3D plot:

```
membrane
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
view(3);
grid on
text(0,-1,.5,'Test','FontSize',20,'Units','data');
```

[image]

moving the text slightly in the y-direction

```
text(0,-0.7,.5,'Test','FontSize',20,'Units','data');
```

gives

[image]

as seen, the text gets cut off (hidden) by the surface.
Is it possible to convert the last position (0,-0.7,.5) to a 2D normalized position?
(Since plotting text in normalized coordinates is not affected (hidden) by the surface). Assume the normalized position is (x,y),
then I could use

```
text(x,y,'Test','FontSize',20,'Units','normalized');
```

to plot the text on the 3D graph.

So my question is: How to convert a 3D data point to a 2D normalized figure point?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following works:

```
h=text(0,-.7,.5,'Test','FontSize',20,'Units','data','visible','off');
set(h,'Units','normalized');
P=get(h,'Position');
x=P(1); y=P(2);
delete(h);
text(x,y,'Test','Color','r','FontSize',20,'Units','normalized');
```